# "in class", "in the lesson", "during the class" or "during the lesson"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> I usually speak very loudly in class.
>
> I usually speak very loudly in the lesson.
>
> I usually speak very loudly during the class.
>
> I usually speak very loudly during the lesson.

I don't see much of difference in these four sentences. What's the best out of these four options (in case there is no other better than these four) to describe the fact that I usually speak loudly when I am in the middle of the process of studying at school. Dictionary doesn't help much in choosing the best phrase here.

Comment: What is your question? The difference between *during* and *in*? *class* vs. *lesson*? One question per post is expected, along with some basic dictionary research at least.

Comment: I've certainly heard your first sentence used the most, though the second sentence doesn't make much sense. Be careful though with _class_ and _lesson_ - in class, the time is not completely spent teaching lessons. Sometimes teachers give work to students to complete using the material they have learned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a classroom teacher myself, I use both “during the lesson” and “in class”, but for students, and for your examples above, “in class” is the more common.

“In class” generally refers to something that happens in the classroom, an event of some kind, whereas “during the lesson” refers more to the learning process and planned activities.

Answer (score 2):

I disagree that the sentences are equivalent. The first sentence omits the definite article. That implies that the behaviour, namely speaking loudly, is habitual whenever "I" is in a class room.

If you include the definite article then that must refer to a specific class, lesson  or whatever. But that is in conflict with the adverb 'usually'. So in my opinion the other three sentences are wrong.

The third sentence is also wrong in that one cannot in English speak "very": that word needs to qualify some other word.

Comment: Why should *usually* be in such conflict? In the class can be specific referring to an implied subject, e.g., math class. If the person listening to me knows which class I'm talking about, then I can say *I usually speak loudly in the (math) class*, can't I?

Answer (score 1):

The sentences are all essentially equivalent.

> What's the best out of these four options

That's hard to say, since "best" is subjective. But "in class" is much more frequent or popular, even if the other three are not wrong.